# strange syntax for returning sign of number in python

Tags: python, syntax, boolean, tuples, list-comprehension

So  the below snippet of code returns the sign of x:

> ```
> x = -15  
> (1, -1)[x < 0]
> ```

I have a hard time understanding WHY this syntax works. In particular, how come you can write a tuple following a list of booleans and get one or the other value in the tuple from that....Someone please explain this syntax!

Comment: nevermind ---i understand now. We are indexing into the tuple with the result of the logical statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a way of doing indexing based on a boolean value. As seen below, `True` and `False` evaluate to `1` and `0` respectively in the context of an integer:

```
>>> int(True)
1
>>> int(False)
0
```

Additionally, `(1, -1)` is a tuple, a sequence object that can be indexed:

```
>>> (314159,271828)[0]
314159
>>> (314159,271828)[1]
271828
```

Combining those two facts, you should be able to discern that:

```
(1, -1)[x < 0]
```

will give you `1` when `x < 0` is false, `-1` when it's true. That's basically the sign of `x`.

Comment: It only took 4 months for someone to answer this apparently basic question ;)

Comment: @DeepSpace: well, it only took a few minutes to work out the answer but I agonised for quite a while over how best to *present* it. Far more worrying is the fact that it took *seven* months to think of something "funny" in response to your comment.  "Funny" is quoted because, as my wife frequently seems to point out, I rarely am :-)